# Securing Grails plugin controllers

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using Grails 2.0.x and the spring security plugin with the default @Secured annotations how can I apply these to secure controllers and actions in a plugin such as the Groovy console plugin?

Given that you can't mix the methods for securing, (i.e. I cannot mix annotations with the interceptUrlMap in Config.groovy) the only way I can think of is to somehow metaProgram the annotation but I don't think this will work either?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See controllerAnnotations.staticRules in section 5 of http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/